# How to compare two rows in a csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've a `data.csv` file which looks as follows.

```
-1.95e+01   -2.30e-01   -2.56e-01   4.44e+01
-1.95e+01   -2.30e-01   -7.68e-01   4.48e+01
-2.00e+01   -2.30e-01   -2.56e-01   3.41e+01
-2.00e+01   -2.30e-01   -7.69e-01   3.46e+01
-2.10e+01   -9.92e+00   1.00e+01    9.66e+01
-2.10e+01   -9.92e+00   2.30e+00    4.29e+01
```

I'd like to have a `result.csv` file such that if the value in the first column is the same, grab all the data in the first four columns (there are 4 columns) and save it in `result.csv` file. Then the next equal values and save it in the next four columns. For example  my `result.csv` should look like

```
-1.95e+01 -2.30e-01 -2.56e-01 4.44e+01 | -2.00e+01 -2.30e-01 -2.56e01 3.41e+01 | -2.10e+01 -9.92e+00 1.00e+01 9.66e+01
-1.95e+01 -2.30e-01 -7.68e-01 4.48e+01 | -2.00e+01 -2.30e-01 -7.69e-01 3.46e+01 | -2.10e+01 -9.92e+00 2.30e+00 4.29e+01
```

My very basic attempt is as follows:

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for col in csv_reader:      
        i = 0
        if col[0] == "Next value of the same column": 'don't know how to fix
            #Grab all the values which have same value in the first column
        else:
            #Grab next values which have same value in the first column
        i += 1
```

Comment: can you post both dataframes and show the values you're trying to match? or are you trying to match the data column wise?

Comment: Your explanation is confusing. Why does `-2.56e-01 ` get added since there is no similar value?

Comment: I just want to take all the values which have same first coloumn entry. i.e. Take all the columns belong to the value -1.95e+01 and save them in a *.csv file and then take the next value in the first coulumn which is -2.00e+01 and do the same but shold follow the structure given in result.csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small point-of-view flaw in your logic: you cannot compare to the "next value" until you've read that value.  Switch your logic such that you retain the previous row in a separate `prev_row` variable.  Then look to see whether the current row matches the previous one; if so, gather the data and append where needed.  If not, "rotate" the just-read row to be `prev_row` and loop back to get the next row from the input file.